How do I run unit tests for single flavor without running all tests?
I'm working on unit tests for my Android app. My app has two flavors: "flavor 1" and "flavor 2", configured in build.gradle. Tests common to both are in test and I also have flavor-specific tests in flavor1Test and flavor2Test.
When I run ./gradlew testFlavor1UnitTest it runs the tests in both test and flavor1Test. Same for flavor 2 and its test folder. But I plan to run the common tests as flavor 1 so I don't need to run them again as flavor 2 (it would be nice if I could but it takes waaaay too long).
How do I run only the tests in only the flavor2Test folder?

To run only the tests in the flavor2Test folder without executing the common tests in the test folder, you can use the following command:
./gradlew testFlavor2UnitTest --tests *flavor2Test.*

Modify the build.gradle file for precise control: If you often want to skip common tests for specific flavors, you can add a custom task or configure the existing testFlavor2UnitTest task to exclude the test sourceset.
In your build.gradle file:
tasks.named("testFlavor2UnitTest") {
    doFirst {
        testClassesDirs = files("build/classes/java/testFlavor2") // Adjust path as needed
        classpath = files(classpath.filter { file ->
            !file.absolutePath.contains("test")
        })
    }
}

This ensures only flavor2Test tests are executed when you run ./gradlew testFlavor2UnitTest.
If your tests are taking too long, consider enabling parallel execution in your build.gradle file:
test {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) // Adjust as needed
}


Sorry but neither solution worked for me.
